# Unreliable cloud for experiments

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, cloud, openstack

I'm in need of an unreliable cloud/cluster of computers that are prone to failures for some experiments I'm doing at school. When I say unreliable, I mean machines may fail or slow down arbitrarily.

Are there any ready services for this? If not, is there any way to get this behavior on readily available clouds (AWS, Azure, Google Cloud) that does not involve just terminating instances?

**EDIT** - Under-provisioning is not allowed for my experiments.

Comment: Depending on what you want to experiments to trigger failure or slow down of instances, maybe you can try setting up and instance on (AWS) with the least resource available in relation to the required resources of your setup - [check instance type for this](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/).

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I should have mentioned under-provisioning is "cheating" for my experiments. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the Cloud provider you choose, there are frameworks built to force shutdowns so that you can test your application's reliability. The [Netflix Simian Army](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/the-netflix-simian-army-16e57fbab116) is a classic example:

> This was our philosophy when we built Chaos Monkey, a tool that
>   randomly disables our production instances to make sure we can survive
>   this common type of failure without any customer impact.

Since you're working on an experiment and decide to go with AWS for any reason, [Spot Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/?nc1=h_ls) may fit your needs. They're low cost with a few drawbacks:

> Spot Instances can be interrupted by EC2 with two minutes of
>   notification when EC2 needs the capacity back.